# Dialogs with labeled slot(s)-value(s)

Tags: data-request, nlp, corpora

I am looking for data sets containing dialogues labeled with slot-values. I am open as to the definition of a dialogue, e.g. message board posts are good too.

---

Definition of slot-values:

A dialog is a sequence of utterances between one or more dialog participants. Dialog participants can be humans, computerized dialog systems, etc. In a dialog system, the goal of the dialog state tracker is to keep track of all dialog states for each utterance. A dialog state represents what dialog participants appear to have in mind. One common representation for a dialog state is a list of slot-value pairs: the slot is a general category, while the value indicates more specifically what the dialog participants have in mind.

Example 1:

[image]

[Example 2](http://www.dfki.de/etai/SpecialIssues/Dia99/araki/araki/node3.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[The Dialog State Tracking Challenge 4](http://www.colips.org/workshop/dstc4/) (DSTC 4): consists of 35 dialog sessions on touristic information for Singapore, collected from Skype calls between three tour guides and 35 tourists. Each dialog session is a dialog between a guide and a tourist, where the guide helps the tourist plan for a trip to Singapore by providing recommendations based on the tourist’s preferences. These **35 dialogs sum up to 31,034 utterances and 273,580 words**. All the recorded dialogs with the total length of **21 hours** have been manually transcribed and annotated with speech act and semantic labels for
each utterance as well as dialog states for each subdialog.
Each dialog is divided into subdialogs, each of which has one topic and contains
one or several utterances. **Dialog states are annotated for each subdialog. A dialog
state is represented as a list of slot-value pairs**.

In case anyone is interested, we presented the state-of-the art dialog state tracker on DSTC 4 in *Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee, Trung H. Bui, and Hung H. Bui. "[Robust Dialog State Tracking for Large Ontologies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02130)". International Workshop on Spoken Dialogue Systems. 2016.*